Avoiding repeat power queries
I am working on developing an input sheet that will use the same data validation and dependent data validation on multiple rows in the same sheet.  I have at least 4 Power Queries in it currently and I am wondering if this is the best approach using a combination of Power Query and Excel formulas.
I have substituted the actual data to protect the guilty.
Query 1 and 2 use data from workbook1, and Query 3 and 4 use data from workbook2.  Query 3 and 4 are a similar process but for different data so I am leaving them out of the question and will use the information garnered from how to properly do Query 1 and 2 and adjust accordingly.
I am aware that this is an image and not posted data.  I will look at added text based source data at the end.
All my source information is layed out in tables and look like the following:

I used the built in ribbon commands to perform a combined power query of the above information to generate the following within the power query editor:

I then proceeded to do some power query operation to combine columns and eliminate excess columns

And then to facilitate 1 level of dependent drop down lists, I pivoted a column and came up with this as my final table which is generated in the work book and I can reference with data validation using indirect function, some concatenation, and the previous columns adjacent cell.

In order to then get the list of projects, I basically repeat steps 1-3 and at step 4, I remove the task column and generate a table in the workbook called Project_List.  Through data validation and indirect I simply do something along the lines of:
=indirect("Project_List")


My input table where I use the data validation looks something like this:


Question
So the sequencing and thought process currently works, but I felt there should be a better way then repeating a query for formatting information that you have already pulled once.  Why pull it again?  Is there a way spit out a table, step back in the processing list and then turn around and spit out another table?  This way you only pull the data once?
With my actual data, I think the combination of Project No and Task number was something like 16K rows.  I think my first attempt was 270K rows, but I made my own workbook and trimmed that information down to the 16K rows.  I also trimmed down the list of interested unique project numbers to about 500.
Sample Data to play with



Project No
Project Name
Project Manager
Office




1
ACME
Wyle E. Coyote
Arizona


2
Hunting Season
Bugs Bunny
Albuquerque


3
Earth Shatter Kaboom
Marvin The Martian
Mars






Project No
Task No
Task Name
Note




1
A
Planning
uua


1
B
Shipping
ytb


1
C
Deployment
ccc


2
A
Carrot Supply
aah


2
D
Avoiding Elmer
yes


3
B
Planning
kib


3
C
Preparation
chh


3
G
Implementation
kgi


3
T
Detonation
tkt



Power Query M to generate Task_List
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("X:\Big Project List.xlsx"), null, true),
    Projects_Tasks_Table = Source{[Item="Projects_Tasks",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Projects_Tasks_Table,{{"Project Number", type text}, {"Project Name", type text}, {"Task Number", type text}, {"Task Name", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Project Name"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each [Task Number]&" - "&[Task Name]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Custom", "Task Np and Name"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Task Name"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1", {{"Project Number", type text}}, "en-CA"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1", {{"Project Number", type text}}, "en-CA")[#"Project Number"]), "Project Number", "Task Np and Name")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"

Power Query M to generate Project_List
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("X:\ Big Project List.xlsx"), null, true),
    Projects_Tasks_Table = Source{[Item="Projects_Tasks",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Projects_Tasks_Table,{{"Project Number", type text}, {"Project Name", type text}, {"Task Number", type text}, {"Task Name", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [Project Number]&" - "&[Project Name]),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Project Number", "Project Name", "Custom", "Task Number", "Task Name"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Custom", "Project Number and Name"}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Project Number and Name", "Task Number", "Task Name"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Project Number and Name", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"

Update
I have set all Query's to delete their data on close and disallowed background refresh.

A Power Query can only generate a single table output. The only way I know of in PQ - Excel is to use Power Query to download the data and do the initial forming. Then load that table into the data model and use Power Pivot / DAX to manipulate the data. Then the data will only be downloaded the one time. However, I don't know if you can get your desired output using Power Pivot in Excel, although you probably could using DAX in Power BI.

@RonRosenfeld OMG - I never thought of such a basic approach.  Please may I chalk that up to the initial learning curve. Power query the basic data once and put it into a table and potentially format it up to the point where your two or more queries split and dump it in a work sheet.  Then follow up with two or more additional queries that get the data to where it needs to be.  In my mind, its got to be faster performing a PQ within your open work book than it is to PQ across a network connection.  Or is my thought process wrong here?

Do all PQs end in a single variable IN

That wan't the approach I was thinking of, but it could work, so long as your data is less than 10^6 rows. And yes, I would expect that loading via a network connection could be much slower than loading from the same workbook, depending on the speed of your network.

Your in line can be a single variable. But it can also contain a formula. You lose being able to see the output of the various steps in that formula. I've never tested to see if it makes any difference in execution time. But sometimes it seems more convenient to code that way.

@RonRosenfeld is 10^6 rows a limitation of PQ?

Just saw this question. No, it is an Excel limitation. See Power Query specifications and limits in Excel

Here's a quick suggestion using formulas and named dynamic ranges:

Using XLOOKUP instead of INDIRECT
Didn't use OFFSET to omit blanks, so there will be blanks at the end
TODO: ensure validation for changes made after the initial selection, for example task may need to be reset if the project is changed

Project_List in K3
=tbProjects[Project No] & " - " & tbProjects[Project Name]

Task_List in L3
=IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("Task List", 
tbProjects[Project No], LAMBDA(acc,cur, 
VSTACK(acc, TRANSPOSE(
FILTER(tbProjectTasks[Task No] & " - " & tbProjectTasks[Task Name], 
tbProjectTasks[Project No] = cur), "")))), 1), "")


Data validation
For B14-
=Project_List

For C14- with C14 selected, fixed column B and relative row 14:
=XLOOKUP($B14,Project_List,Task_List)



Interesting I will have to try that out.  I was using indirect because I was getting errors referencing tables.  I thought the only option was to reference the table via calling the name from within the indirect function.  Then again I may be getting that requirement mix up between data validation and conditional formatting.

You're right - we cannot use 'structured references' directly in conditional formatting and validation; but you could via to some extent via names. These two expect references to ranges either directly or indirectly, so using names with spill ranges offer some flexibility.
